# Getting reviews from 3rd party sites

Tags: php, api, screen-scraping

I see a lot of sites showing this, but on Groupon in particular for a merchant, they will show Reviews from CitySearch, Yelp (I think), TripAdviser, Open Table, Frommers, etc.

Do all these sites provide API's? I can't find them or would Groupon be scraping the sites?

Any ideas how to get this same type of data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically all the sites you've listed have API's to allow for various bits of information to be extracted, for example Trip Advisors can be found here: http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/help/what_is_an_api

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you give Needlebase a try. A free account gives the public access to your scrapped data, but its a great tool.

http://needlebase.com

How to use it/Example:

http://www.needlebase.com/videos

Note: Get permission from the site before hand/ check the laws in your country regarding scraping.